# How to load several images in jasper report?

Tags: java, database, jasper-reports

I have an entity who contains this field:

```
public class SomeReport {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    ....
    private InputStream image;
}
```

JRXML have following code:

```
<field name="image" class="java.io.InputStream"/>
```

```
<image>
    <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="560" height="560" uuid="56562e30-3e6f-48fb-b37a-979f6f5739f5"/>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{image}]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

Table in my db have column `attachemntIds`. This column have type `JSONB` and contains list of ID's in the format `[1, 2,...n]`
I get from DB this list and want to displaying all of this images to report.

I can change `InputStream` for `List<InputStream>`. How should I change the JRXML so that all the pictures are shown?

Comment: You can use list component, for example

Comment: @AlexK can you attach sample code?

Comment: Show me an example of the json and I will pass an answer if you ping me in comment